# How can I draw a point or line on a map in j2me?

Tags: java-me, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I want know how to draw a point on a map that comes from the user's GPS values in a j2me language. Is the map of a city an image (png) or what?

Comment: I've tried to update your post to better address what you are trying to accomplish.  hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible with J2ME.

you have to pass latitude longitude as request and you will get map

as a response you will get image(Image formate you specified in request).

follow the [tutorial](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Google_Maps_API_in_Java_ME) it will help you.

Comment: it dose not work well this techneges with my cuntry , i live in ( iraq-mosul) there is no static image form my counter , can any one help me